# Copy email body to Excel using Outlook VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to copy the body of an email to a new Excel workbook.

The code is generating an error

> "Object Required"

on the `Set Wb` line.

A majority of this code is copied from somewhere else, but it's been a while and I forget where.

```vb
Sub PasteToExcel()
    Dim activeMailMessage As MailItem
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim Wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim Ws As Excel.Worksheet
    
    If TypeName(ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)) = "MailItem" Then

        'Get a handle on the email
        Set activeMailMessage = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

        'Copy the formatted text:
        activeMailMessage.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Copy
    
        'Ensure Excel Application is open
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

        'Make Excel Application visible
        xlApp.Visible = True

        'Name the Excel File
        Set Wb = xlObject.Object.Workbooks("Test.xlsx")
    
        'Paste the email
        Set Ws = xlObject.Object.Sheets(1)
        Ws.Range("A1").Paste
    
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `xlObject` ?  Do you mean `xlApp.Workbooks()` ?

Comment: I made that change and it gives me a subscript out of range error.

Comment: Where does it give you that error?

Comment: change `Xlobjet.object `to `xlApp`.

Comment: This gives me the out of range error                                                         Set Wb = xlApp.Workbooks("Test.xlsx")

Comment: Test.xlsx is opened...?

Comment: Test.xlsx does not exist.  I need the macro to create a new workbook and name it that.

Comment: use add method to create that with name "Test"

Comment: You posted a question about an "object required" error, you got an answer addressing the "object required" error (and more!) - editing your question a whole week later to ask a completely different question about how to go about copying the contents of an Outlook email *defeats the purpose of this site* - this isn't a discussion forum, it's Q&A. If you have a new question, mark this one as accepted and then *ask a new question* - don't edit your post to make every previous answering effort moot.

Answer (score 3):

`xlObject` isn't declared or assigned anywhere. Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of the module - the VBE will likely be complaining about the undeclared identifier.

Because `xlObject` isn't declared, it's implicitly `Variant`, and because it's never assigned, its type is actually `Variant/Empty`. And because `Empty` isn't an object type, using the `Set` keyword to assign an object reference causes that "Object required" error, because `Set` can only be used to assign an object reference.

This code reproduces the issue - try it in the *immediate pane*:

```
Set foo = xyz.abc
```

In other words, `xlObject` doesn't exist, VBA doens't know what to do with it. As you've been told in comments, you need to use the properly declared and assigned `xlApp` reference instead.

```
Set Wb = xlApp.Workbooks("Test.xlsx")
```

> *This gives me the out of range error*

Of course it does. There's no workbook named `Test.xlsx` in that instance of Excel.

The solution is to open it:

```
Set Wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Test.xlsx")
```

Now, you should be expecting another error if that file doesn't exist: *handle it*.

> *Test.xlsx does not exist. I need the macro to create a new workbook and name it that.*

The `Add` method will create a brand new workbook:

```
Set Wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
```

You can name the workbook when you save it, before you close it:

```
wb.SaveAs "test.xlsx"
wb.Close False
```

The `Close` method has parameters to save changes, so you could also do it in one line:

```
wb.Close True, "test.xlsx"
```